# boost convinience header does not include required header

Tags: boost-asio

I'm trying to use boost's network_v4 class and included `boost/asio.hpp` convenience header as stated in documentation [network_v4](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__network_v4.html).
Actually it's not included there and I get `'network_v4': is not a member of 'boost::asio::ip'` error. Only including `boost/asio/ip/network_v4.hpp` header solves the issue. Is this normal?

Comment: You can check `asio.hpp` file. It doesn't include `network_v4.hpp`. Since `network_v4` is a new addition(10 month ago). My guess is that the author simply forgot to add it in.